# How do I determine if a record already exists in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datatable

I have a DataTable that I am binding it to a GridView on my ASP.NET page. I also allow editing and insertion.

Upon saving/insertion, I need to determine if there is a duplicate description in the Gridview.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: When you looked at the documentation for DataTable on MSDN, did you not find an applicable method to use? What problem did you have with it?

Comment: Reading is hard and I would rather have someone else do the work.

Comment: How are you checking ROW duplicacy ... are you checking all the field in a row? OR a specific field to determine uniqueness

Comment: When you add then iteratre the Datatable and check that if it has the same ID (primary key- assuming) in it.

Answer (score 2):

Any way the data which you are binding will have the unique id. 
So after  binding check for that id whether it is there or not in datatable.We can't say more than this unless you explain it more.

Answer (score 1):

We may need some more information on what kind of database you are using to give you the right answer, but I'll take a swing anyway.

First, you need to have a PRIMARY KEY on your database table for several reasons including a default index and insuring uniqueness.  Second, you can configure the table to have a UNIQUE INDEX on the description column.  This will prevent the insertion of duplicate data at the database level.  But, once you do that you will likely get some kind of exception or error in your client application that you will need to catch and handle.

Also, you could create an AJAX function to filter the data as the user types in the new row and show them records that are similar.  I did this on an app where the users would put in the same request but use slightly different wording.